# Flask, Jinja2, Plotly: callback click event data from website to Python script

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Using Flask as a web framework, Jinja2 for templates, and Plotly for graphics. I can create bar or scatter plots and now want to set up an onClick event: click on a data point and call back a Python script with the x, y, index information of that data point. I thought, importing a function via the context processor would work. However, it works only for static information as in var pts = {{ utility(0) }}, but not for dynamic information as in var pts = {{ utility(data.points[0].pointNumber) }}. Error message: >jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'data' is undefined. I assume, the context processor works before the website is rendered, and so doesn't find that variable at that time. However, the standard alert function does work. So, what happens behind the scene, and how can I make my context function work similarily?

My Python script

```
from flask import Flask, render_template    
import plotly, plotly.graph_objs as go
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def utility(index):
        with open('junk.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write('data index: %i' % index)
        return str(index)
    return dict(utility=utility)

def create_plot():
    data = [go.Bar(x=[1,2],y=[3,4])]
    graphJSON = json.dumps(data, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    return graphJSON

@app.route('/')
def junk():
    plot=create_plot()
    return render_template('junk.html', plot=plot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My website:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
        <div id="plotDiv">
        <script>
            var myPlot = document.getElementById('plotDiv');
            var graphs = {{plot | safe}};
            Plotly.newPlot(myPlot, graphs, {}, {});
            myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
                var pts = {{ utility(0) }};
                var pts = {{ utility(data.points[0].pointNumber) }};
                alert(
                    'alert: '+data.points[0].x+', '+data.points[0].y +
                    '\nutility: '+pts);
            });
        </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```